# sharepoint in infrastructure managemant services

Tags: sharepoint, infrastructure

Is sharepoint being used in infrastructure management services(ITIS)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out one of the case studies on this:

SharePoint 2010: AvePoint's infrastructure management tools are built on SharePoint
http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/abe1bff1-bfff-4ff9-b21d-9952f331a5a3

Answer (score 0):

yes, sharepoint is being used in infrastructure management services(ITIS).